# How Can I Label An Image And Use It As A Button?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my icon work as buttons but I want to use an image instead. The guide im following uses this code in html:

```html
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="menu-btn">
<label for="menu-btn" class="btn menu-btn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
```

But I want to use an image and my code looks like this:

```html
<input type="radio" name="slide" id="menu-btn">
<img for="menu-btn" class="btn menu-btn" src="menubcf.png" alt="" width="30" height="20">
```

My goal is to have a menu that can be opened and closed like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB28hKxvN38&t=839s).

Application test images are available below:

1. [Menu Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJclq.png)
2. [Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixz0a.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type="radio" name="slide" id="menu-btn">
<label for="menu-btn" class="btn menu-btn">
  <img for="menu-btn" class="btn menu-btn" src="menubcf.png" alt="" width="30" height="20">
</label>
```

`<i>` Tag is used for call [FontAwsome](https://fontawesome.com/) icons.

Comment: If you don't like label tag, you could use JS with onclick function ;)

Comment: Omg thank you so much!! Been driving me crazy feel like I tried every thing. Thanks agiain

Comment: And it's an assignment so I can only use html and css :)

Comment: The attribute `for` on <label> tag must be equal to the `id` attribute of the related element. This mechanism bind them together :)